# Export Chrome History with Powershell

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

I'm doing a school Project and I'm trying to Export the Chrome Search History into a CSV file I spent alot of hours trying but didn't got any result.

I'm glad for any help

Greets
Maiko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/rvrsh3ll/Misc-Powershell-Scripts/blob/master/Get-BrowserData.ps1) and get browser data like Histroy or Bookmarks of browsers like `Chrome`, `FireFox` and `IE`

To invoke : `Get-BrowserData -Browser Chrome -Datatype History -UserName user1`